# Remove TabBar item in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I currently try to find a way to remove while run the app a TabBar Item, i found a way to enable or disable it but not to complete remove it.

For disable it i do:

[image]

In ViewDidLoad

```
if let tabBarItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3] as? UITabBarItem {
            tabBarItem.enabled = false
}
```

This works well but still the user can see the TabBar item and i ll simply complete remove it, is there a way?

I want to trigger the TabBarItem via Parse, if i set the Parse Data to true it should show other way it should not.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You want to set the `viewControllers` property of your `tabBarController` with an array where you excluded the particular viewController that you don't want to have anymore.

```
if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {
    let indexToRemove = 3
    if indexToRemove < tabBarController.viewControllers?.count {
        var viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers
        viewControllers?.remove(at: indexToRemove)
        tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know how to get it to come back after you've removed it?

Comment: I know this is quite old now, but regarding 'how do you get it back?' - keep a reference to the original (e.g. in viewDidLoad take a copy of the original viewControllers array) so that you can revert back to it whenever you wish.

Comment: @Adam Did you find any solution to add it back?

Comment: Note: Do not remove ViewControllers inside TabBarController. Remove them when you are pushing TabBarController screen.

Comment: As a note I ran this code to remove a tab bar item in the view did load of my first screen, but it crashed due to an out of bounds error with the view controller's array. I forcefully ran this on the main thread using DispatchQueue and it worked afterwards

Answer (score 13):

For those who just want to disable one item. Use this code from @Daniele's solution. and place it in your UITabBarController class

```
viewDidLoad() {

let index = 0 //0 to 5
viewControllers?.remove(at: index)

}
```

Comment: do you have know to get it to come back after removing it?

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5:  For removing only one index in Tab Bar Controller(you can use this method in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear both of them)

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

tabBarController.viewControllers?.remove(at:0)  // for 0 index
tabBarController.viewControllers?.remove(at:1)  // for 1 index
tabBarController.viewControllers?.remove(at:2)  // for 2 index
```

if you have 4 index in Tab Bar and you want to remove the last 2 index

```
tabBarController.viewControllers?.remove(at:2)
tabBarController.viewControllers?.remove(at:2)
```

first line will remove the index 3rd one and you will remaining 3 from 4 and again when you remove the 2nd index it will remove again 3rd index and then you will have remain 2 index in last.

Another Way

```
//MARK: - Function Call
removeTab(at: 4)

//MARK: - Method
func removeTab(at index: Int) {
    if self.viewControllers?.count ?? 0 >= index {
        self.viewControllers?.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4.1**
For removing More items Use Array

```
let index = [2,0]
index.forEach{viewControllers?.remove(at: $0)}
```

the point in the array is You Should Use Descending Order of indexes to remove to get the desired Result.

Answer (score -10):

better way is to use only text instead of image.    choose 'space' as the text then disable that.  then the user will not be able to see it.   i haven't tested it but I sure it will work.