# How to hide tabs in tabBarController dynamically in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, ios11

I am using UITabBarController and added tabs using relationship segue from storyboard.

How to hide particular tab according to logged in user role?

Comment: Could you elaborate the question? you might also need to add a code snippet of what have you tried so far...

Answer (score 4):

Nice question!

You need to dig [UITabbarController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller) and its members (properties + functions)

Now, focus on these steps to find solution:

1. You can create as many tabbar (item) as you want, using View controllers assocated with it by Segue. Connect all view controllers with tabbar (controller) using segue in your story board.
2. Now, about [UITabbarController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller): It has a property (variable) `viewControllers` (which an array of UIViewController) that stores UIViewControllers for your Tabbar Controller associated using UITabbar items.
3. You need to store a value, that indicates user login status, in permanent storage (like [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults), [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html),....) of device.
4. When your application launches, retrieve/get that value (user login status) from storage and use it for further operations on UITabbarController.
5. Now focus on step 2: Get all view controllers programatically from your tabbar controller using property 'viewControllers` and store in separate variable.
6. Interchange/Exchange/Update position (index) of ViewControllers in array (You can also remove or insert view controller programatically) according to your requirement (login status) and reassign the same array (variable) to `viewControllers` property of tabbar controller.

Here is sample example on application launch:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if var tabController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabbarController, var viewControllers = tabController.viewControllers {

       let isLoggedIn = <get value from your data storage as bool>

       if  isLoggedIn {
           viewControllers.remove(at: firstIndex)  // By considering you need to remove view controller at index first. It will automatically remove tab from tabbar also.
           tabController.viewControllers = viewControllers
           self.window?.rootViewController = tabController
           // further operations to make your root controller visible....
       }

   }

}
```

Comment: How to initialise window? Sorry I'm new to ios, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384321/remove-tabbar-item-in-swift] also referred this link but its not worked

Comment: In my code - `self.window?` is property of `AppDelegate`. You not need to initialize it. Just create Your tabbar controller from storyboard. Assign main storyboard and root constroller as tabbar to your project from your storyboard. This code with automatically work.

Comment: I have login as root controller. User logged in successfully then TabBarController is open.I have already added all the tabs in TabBarController from storyBoard and its working fine. Now I want to show and hide view controllers according to user role (which I get from server in login response)

Comment: Response from server-
"featuresAction" : “[{\”Frature1\”:[\”View\”]},{\”Frature2\”:[\”View\"]},{\"Frature3\”:[\”View\"]},{\"Frature4\”:[\”View\"]},{\"Frature5\”:[\”View\"]}]"

This is response and I want to hide tabs according to feature list(which I get from server)

Comment: TabBarControllers:
        <connections>
        <segue destination="Un3-mu-Kf6" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="yJt-7I-uo6”/>. //Frature1
        <segue destination="9c0-EJ-Vgl" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="pJK-Qe-03b”/>. //Frature2
        <segue destination="6EP-pL-ham" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="Mbg-5x-zNT”/>. //Frature3
        <segue destination="yWR-hT-wiF" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="2tD-Ah-cyT”/>. //Frature4

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove tabs from your tab bar controller do something like this (When your user is not logged in)

```
NSInteger indexToRemove = 0;
NSMutableArray *tabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
[tabs removeObjectAtIndex:indexToRemove];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = tabs;
```

when your user logs in

```
UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *tabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.tabBarController.viewControllers];
[tabs addObject:viewController];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = tabs;
```

Swift Version

**Remove tab**

```
let indexToRemove = 0
if var tabs = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers {
  tabs.remove(at: indexToRemove)
  self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = tabs
} else {
  print("There is something wrong with tabbar controller")
}
```

**Add tab**

```
let indexToAdd = 2
let vc = UIViewController.init()
if var tabs = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers {
  tabs.append(vc) // Append at last index of array
  // tabs.insert(vc, at: indexToAdd)  // Insert at specific index
  self.tabBarController?.viewControllers = tabs
} else {
  print("There is something wrong with tabbar controller")
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what issue caused?

Comment: In remove tab code getting error at 2nd line as EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0*0)

Comment: @ShubhangiShedage Please check my edit, and sorry i did not tested my code.

Comment: @PratikJamariya, Dear, don't unwrap viewcontrollers of tabbar controller forcefully. It may result into app crash `(self.tabBarController?.viewControllers)!`. Try `if-let`to prevent app crash.

Comment: @Krunal please feel free to edit my answer, i am not good at swift, but my Objective-C skills are very sound.