# How i implemented an Tab into UITabBar without seeing this tab as item?

Tags: swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I have an UITabBarController which has 5 Tabs. So, my problem is, i want to make an welcome screen into the UITabBarController, but this screen should be just only one time visible, when the app started. After the screen appears and the user switch the Tabs, he can't go back to the welcome screen, otherwise he must quit the app and open it again.

I tried to make an UIViewController as an RootViewController, but he dont show me the UITabBarController instead.

Is there any way that i can solve this problem over the storyboard? Also with code it will be also okay.

Answer (score 0):

If I did not misunderstand your  question these ideas will help you;

Add an extra tab to your tabBarViewController , make it welcome view and  make this view controller initial VC so user when landing to tabBarViewController this view will appear after few seconds change tab index `selectedIndex` as you desire from UITabBarViewController then hide welcome view button from tabBar.

Seond way : Inside UItabbarViewController create custom tabbarView (scrollable) you can use collectionView it's easy to implement and it cells selectable like buttons.  Hide original tabbar make welcome view appears first, make its index sixth then change selectedIndex programmatically when you need and disable scrolling from collectionView with this way only your five buttons appears on screen and welcome view button automatically remain out of screen.

You can find example code in my Github repo [UICWaveTabBar](https://github.com/Coder-ACJHP/UICWaveTabBar/tree/master/UICWaveTabbar/UICWaveTabBar), [UICSlideTabBar](https://github.com/Coder-ACJHP/UICWaveTabBar/tree/master/UICWaveTabbar/UICSlideTabBar) , [UICExapandableTabBar](https://github.com/Coder-ACJHP/UICWaveTabBar/tree/master/UICWaveTabbar/UICExpandableTabBar)

Fist link including .xib file, you can edit it from storyboard, second and third only code

Comment: okay, i have a static UITabBarController in my Storyboard, so i think i can't hide just one UITabBarItem. I just can hide the complete UITabBar. Thanks for your Answer by the way.

Comment: You can easily,  just look at this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28384731/6296931