# How can I hide a UITabbarIcon?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I'm currently developing an iOS-App which will have 5 tabbar-icons. One of these should only be visible if you are allowed to see it. 
How can I hide this icon?

Comment: You can add / remove tabBarItems at run time to achieve this.

Comment: self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true/false

Comment: @BhavikModi How can I do that?

Comment: @YogeshPatel This hides the complete tabbar not a specific icon.

Comment: Okay try this way tabBarController.viewControllers?.remove(at:0)

Comment: also check this url :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28384321/remove-tabbar-item-in-swift this question is already ask many times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the `UIViewController` from `tabBar`, add this line of code in the `UITabBarControllerClass`

For removal

```cs
self.viewControllers?.remove(at: tabIndex) // replace the tabIndex which you want to remove
```

For Add

```cs
self.viewControllers?.insert(viewController, at: tabIndex) // replace the viewcontroller with your controller and tabIndex with your index
```

Comment: I did it in a ViewController with `self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?` instead of in the UITabBarControllerClass.
This did work too.

Answer (score 0):

With the following code, you can remove the specified tab from tab bar:

```
let tabIndex = 3
if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {
    if tabIndex < tabBarController.viewControllers?.count {
        var allViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers
        allViewControllers?.remove(at: tabIndex)
        tabBarController.viewControllers = allViewControllers
    }
}
```